# access to fx:id fields between different controller classes / fxml nested files

Tags: javafx, fxml

I followed the thread of .../40836043/javafx-access-fxid-from-nested-fxml to add access to fields between 2... Controller classes while using a fx:include structure,  but I seem to step into a problem:

My voxeledit.fxml (the root fxml file for VoxelEdit.java) is

```
<VBox minHeight="766.0" ..... 
         ....                  
    <fx:include source="VoxelEditModelTabs.fxml"           fx:id="modeltabsController" />
         .... 
</VBox>
```

and the associated Controller java is

```
 public class VoxelEditController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private VoxelEditModelTabsController       modeltabsController;
....
   @Override
     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         System.out.println( ". VoxelEditController initializing ..." );

         System.out.println( ". VoxelEditController voxeleditModeltabsController is: "+modeltabsController );
 ....
```

and then the controller for the embedded fxml is

```
public class VoxelEditModelTabsController implements Initializable {

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
      System.out.println( ". VoxelEditModelTabsController initialized" );
   }  

   private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper status_msg = new   ReadOnlyStringWrapper();

   public ReadOnlyStringProperty status_msg_Property() { 
       return status_msg.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
   }
....
```

when running the main app, it stops after some debug messages from the main initialze process

```
*** VoxelEdit main started
*   VoxelEdit start entered
. VoxelEditMenuController initializing
. VoxelEditColorSelectionController initialized
. VoxelEditModelTabsController initialized

Exception in Application start method
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set voxeledit.VoxelEditModelTabsController field voxeledit.VoxelEditController.modeltabsController to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
```

If I remove the fx:id from the fx:include, the app runs but the field modelTabs in class VoxelEditController stays NULL.

As the message "can not set ..." is not really helpful, I do not know what is wrong. I merged all fx:include pieces into one large fxml and the app then runs, BUT this is not what I think should be modularized development (btw, the fxml file is having more than 1500 lines)!

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: The `fx:id` is wrong: if the field name *for the controller* is `modeltabsController`, the `fx:id` should be `fx:id="modeltabs"`. (To understand the error message: The `fx:id` is going to define a reference to the root element of the included FXML file (which looks like it is an `AnchorPane` in this case): hence the error occurs because the type in the controller doesn't match.)

Comment: Ah yes. This solved it and I have learned something ! Thank you very much for that fast solution. I can now go forward and test all the 12 included parts ...